# Is there a way to recover or restore a deleted partition from a BigQuery Table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

Is there a way to recover or restore a deleted partition from a BigQuery Table? Or is there a way to create a new partition but specifying a "creation_time" for that partition when creating it?

I found this on the Official Documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#sql_1

[image]

As you can see there is a meta tag called "creation_time", but don't know if it is possible to change or create a new partition putting other date instead of the current one when you create.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question that if it is possible to change or create a new partition putting other date instead of the current one, you will get the error "Cannot replace a table with a different partitioning spec. Instead, DROP the table, and then recreate it..."  Hope that clarifies.

[image]